# Maven Testing - How can I get current Maven Settings from Java

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin, oracle-ucm

I'm building integration testing for a WCC-Component in Maven.

In mavens `pom.xml` I have a plugin configured too:

1. Build the component
2. deploy the component
3. enable the component
4. restart the component

Once that is complete I'm working on Getting the **Maven-Failsafe-Plugin** to test the installed plugin.

Before I can test the plugin I need to set some things up.  I decided the easiest way would be to create a parent class for my Integration tests that would only initialize if it hadn't been run already.

Example:

```
@BeforeClass
public static initialize()
{  
   //lazy init here
}
```

since my component is already installed/enabled from the maven configuration I want to leverage that information instead of duplicating it for the integration tests.

In my `pom.xml` I have:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.ucmtwine</groupId>
  <artifactId>ucm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions> <!-- Allows WCC packaging type -->
  <configuration>
    <servers>
      <server>            
        <id>sandbox</id>
        <url>http://localhost:16200/cs/idcplg</url>
        <username>myUser</username>
        <password>myPass</password>
        <adminServer>
          <hostname>localhost</hostname> 
          <serverName>AdminAServer</serverName> 
          <wlsServerName>UCM_server1</wlsServerName> 
        </adminServer>
      </server>
    </servers>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

How can I access that information from my `@BeforeClass` initialization method?  Additionally my Maven plugin also supports `-Dserver` so the user can choose which server configuration to use (based on ID).  How would I access that parameter as well?

**Note:** I am not using `settings.xml` for this.

Comment: You're talking about a WCC component AND a maven-plugin. Which of the two did you developer (or did you do both?)

Comment: @RobertScholte I created both; https://github.com/raystorm/ucm-maven-plugin the current question is about using plugin config in my component testing.

Comment: @Raystorm Your repository does not allow to open issues..cause this plugin used plugins as dependencies which I bet on is simply wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated my github repo to accept issues.  Please file an issue and we can discuss the reasons, and possible alternatives there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you shouldn't try to do this. The `settings.xml` as a typical Maven file accessible by Maven and Maven Plugins. The component is a standalone piece of code, you shouldn't try to mix these two.
I can think of several options:

- feed your component integration test with the right configuration, e.g. via system properties or properties file. In both cases you probably need to have an extra maven-plugin the prepare this (during pre-integration-test). However, this makes it a bit harder to directly run within you IDE.
- use your maven-plugin to do the real integration tests of the component. In the end this is probably also the preferred way of how the component is used.
- Don't use maven-failsafe-plugin for this. Make a separate Java project for integration testing where you control the environment settings.

The first two matches closest to your requirements, but I'd prefer the third option.

Comment: I've attempted to clarify my answer that I'm not using the `settings.xml` file.

Comment: Okay, but it doesn't really change the situation. The component is not used within a Maven context, so it should not try to use Maven specific information. If your goal is to have 1 location with configuration for both tests, then both the plugin and component must be able to handle that file. Giving the plugin an option configureFromFile is possible, but ugly. You should  wonder if testing one with some configuration is enough to cover all for the other.